# Library is API 23, I'm using API 23 - android image picker

Tags: android

I am looking for library of image picker / selector. There are many libraries on github (camera and gallery) but all of these great codes are using API 23. 
I'm using API 22 and as you predict, there is conflict.

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Mostly with this, what means that I cannot use it with API 22.

Is there any way to fix it? Or if not, do you know some older library? API 22 is must have for me, I cannot use API 23.

Answer (score 0):

for views like this, sometimes you can use the compatibility layer https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html but maybe this only works for backwards compatibility?

The other method would be to replace the items in the UI Layout that are relying on these new APIs

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to force using library:

```
<uses-sdk 
   tools:node="merge"
   android:minSdkVersion="22"
   android:targetSdkVersion="24"/>
```

But that is **not the recommended** ways because the library could use specific code from API Level 23. So it can make your application crash.

You can also try to fork the library and change the library to meet your minimum SDK requirements.

For other image picker library, try to visit http://android-arsenal.com/tag/157